# Minimal area of triangle

Tags: geometry, optimization, area

We have the points $A(2, 3-m), B(m+2, -1)$ and $C(m, 2-m)$.
Where $m$ is a real number. Find $m$ for which the area of triangle $ABC$ is minimal.

So I've tried to find the equation of line $BC$(the base), find its length and then find the length from $A$ to $BC$($AA'$, the height of the triangle).

I got something like this in the end:

$$\mathrm{Area} = \left|-m^2+4m-9\right|\frac{\sqrt{4+(3-m)^2}}{2\sqrt{2m^2+18)}}$$

I'm checking my equation for the area right now, but is this the correct way to find the area? And how do I find m for which the area is minimal?

Comment: Can other approach be used,like using the Shoelace Formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Use:
$$
Area=\dfrac{1}{2}\left|
\begin {matrix}
x_A-x_B&y_A-y_B\\
x_A-x_C&y_A-y_C
\end{matrix}
\right|
$$
where the determinant i is the area (with sign!) of the parallelogram with sides $A-B$ and $A-C$

Comment: I get Area = $1/2(-m^2+5m-8)$ How do I minimize this function? :S

Comment: You are forgetting the absolute value.

Comment: Yes, you are right @egreg. Well then, the minimal value that expression could have is 0, but delta is negative for that value and m must be real. If I derive the function first as $-m^2+5m-8$ and then as $m^2-5m+8$ and then equIize it to 0, I'd get m = 5/2 which would give the the value of the expression of 7/4. Is this the minimum?

Comment: It's the vertex of a parabola, so you can easely see if it is a minimum or maximum. No derivative is needed.

Comment: You don't have to derive: $m^2-5m+8$ is a quadratic polynomial, and it's a basic fact that $a x^2+bx+c$ attains its  minimum (or maximum, depending on the sign of $a$) is attained at $\,x=-\dfrac b{2a}$.